# Can X-rays travel quicker than visible light in a medium?

Tags: optics, speed-of-light, refraction, dispersion, x-rays

I have seen while reading a few books that the refractive index depends on lambda as follows by the Cauchy equation.

$${\displaystyle \eta(\lambda )=A+{\frac {B}{\lambda ^{2}}}}$$

From this, the book concluded that X-rays travel slower in a refractive medium than visible light.

My question was why should the Cauchy Coefficient **B** be greater than $0$?

If it actually is greater than 0 for all cases, is there a fundamental reason for it, as refraction at the end of the day is a kind of "forced oscillation" and we can derive whatever we want by solving the Maxwell equations.

If it isn't necessary for it to be greater than $0$, in what cases is it positive/negative? And if it can be negative are there any materials found?

When I delved into google trying to find B values for various materials, all of them had $B>0$.

[image: Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_equation]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_equation

Please explain why that's the case theoretically, there even exist metamaterials existing with $\eta<0$, so it seemed weird why $B>0$. I also couldn't find a proof for the Cauchy equation so help me out how to proceed(Isnt it just an emphirical relation).

Whatever the exact Cauchy equation is, my main question is should $\eta$ always decrease with lambda? Is there a formula that dictates the value of B, and how do I derive one.

Comment: Generally speaking, the Lorentz model for the index of refraction would imply that, the higher the energy of the photon, the lower the index of refraction. Well, except near transitions excited by a given wavelength. Now, you skipped the part in Wikipedia where it says "The theory of light-matter interaction on which Cauchy based this equation was later found to be incorrect. In particular, the equation is only valid for regions of normal dispersion in the visible wavelength region." - It has little bearing on the x-ray limit.

Comment: @JonCuster, that seems like an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @rob - I think we have determined experimentally that I'm bad about 'answering' in comments. In my defense, I'm often not interested in spending the time to craft an answer that is completely satisfactory to me... Mea culpa.

Comment: @JonCuster Feel free to post partially-satisfactory answers with a disclaimer about how you hope to return and improve them later. Note also that “hope to improve later” and “plan to improve later” are slightly different things.

Answer (score 0):

Cauchy' dispersion relation is a simple model devised for visible light in very weakly absorbing media. Coefficients $A,B,C$ can be determined by fitting the experimental results.

It is not applicable to X-rays or higher frequency radiation. Index of refraction of such high frequency radiation is often close to 1, and sometimes slightly smaller than 1 (so the phase speed is higher than $c$).

See e.g. [https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~attwood/sxr2009/lecnotes/04_Reflection_And_Refraction_2009.pdf](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eattwood/sxr2009/lecnotes/04_Reflection_And_Refraction_2009.pdf)

Comment: I do know that the Cauchy Dispersion relation is an empirical relation for special cases. So you are suggesting that higher the frequency we cant say with certainty the phase velocity will become lesser? I just used the cauchy coefficients as an example. My question was a bit general, why should phase velocity become lesser and frequency increase, it all depends on the lifetime of the excited state, which would be higher/lower for frequencies. But in my exams we assumed on increasing the frequency the velocity decreased, can we be certain that this law holds for all type of radiation,materials

Comment: No, the Cauchy relation isn't general at all, do not assume phase speed increases or decreases with frequency increasing; this depends on material and frequency, there is no general monotonic relation.

Comment: Great so the answer given in my book is false?

Comment: Isn't the Sellemier equation a general monotonic relation??